# Does one have to eat in a sukkah if they were going to eat outside anyways?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, sukkot, eating

If a sukkah is a temporary replacement for a home, does one need to eat in a sukkah if they were in a park or at a restaurant?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Precovid most diners ate indoors at restaurants. I don't know what you're talking about with restaurants

Comment: If someone is traveling for a legitimate reason (leisure is subject to a machlokes) and there is no succah available, he doesn’t need to build one or spend extensive time searching for one, just like he would do if it wasn’t succos. Therefore if your in a park with no succah you can eat. However, R Moshe held that in such a case you shouldn’t go to the park. Others hold that although your patur, your still avoiding a mitzvah, like not wearing tzitzis etc

Comment: Don't take my word for it; ask a Rav. But from the Gemara (Sukkah 26a), Shulchan Aruch (O.C. 640:8) rules that people travelling by day are exempt from Sukkah in the daytime. Mishna Berura (39 and 40) explains: There are reasons that a person leaves his house, and this would exempt his from Sukkah also, since the law dwelling in a Sukkah (Teshvu) is no stricter that the normal fashion in which one lives in his house (K'ein Teduru)l thus, unless there is a Sukkah right in front of you in which you could eat without any effort, you can eat in the park/restaurant in which you find yourself.